# What is the best practical way of testing a multilingual application in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-i18n

Suppose that I have a rails app that has 4 languages those german, english, french and swedish. I want to test this app with rspec for all locales. At the moment I test it like below.

```
I18n.available_locales = [:en, :de, :fr,:sv]


describe "Example Pages" do   

  subject { page }

  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|

    describe "example page" do
      let(:example_text) { t('example.translation') }

      before { visit example_path(locale) }

      it { should have_selector('h1', text: example_text) }
      ...
    end
    ...   
  end
end
```

But to test the app for all locale I have to loop avalaible locales for every spec and this is a very painful process. I am looking for a very simple way to test for multilingual without injecting a locale loop for every spec. How can do that?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69819/using-i18n-in-capybara-feature-specs

Comment: This does not fit my question. I want to test the app for every language. I do not ask how to test with i18n. My question is totally different.

Comment: This really depends on what you want to test. If you want to test that the translations are complete you can turn on the option in `config/environments/test.rb` to raise exceptions for missing translations - if you want to test that the correct translation keys are used in the view you would do what you have done above - however doing it in each locale gives no extra value. Using loops in specs is generally considered a pretty bad code smell.

Comment: When using i18n sometimes specific errors may occur. Yes, this a bad code practice but it should be considered to test the app for every locale. We should know exactly that the app passes all locales. This is my opinion.

Comment: In this case you are still only testing that the views contains the correct I18n key - a faulty translation such as a submit button reading "ich bin eine kartoffel" (German: I am a potato) will still pass the spec. 

I would recommend testing critical "happy paths" with literal strings in each locale instead which ensures the button says something like "Einreichen" instead. This leads to tons of duplication however and means that updating translations will break the test suite.